# Построение графика ряда Python

Tags: python, математика

[image: Ряд Фурье для sgnx]

У меня есть ряд Фурье, мне нужно для него написать цикл и вывести график этого ряда
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
print("Задаем N")
N=int(input())
x=0

summ=[]

y=np.sign(x)



for x in np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi+0.01, 0.01):
    for k in range(1,N+1):
        sum1+=np.sin((2*k+1)*x)/(2*k+1)
    sum1=sum1*(4/np.pi)
    summ.append(sum1)
    sum1=0
print(summ)
```

Шаг использую 0.01, дальше использую plt.plot но не могу понять, как расположить аргументы этой ф-ии, чтобы получить график.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi+0.01, 0.01)
plt.plot(x,summ)
```